# Javascript file is not excuted after load content with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'd like to load content inside a modal , it works good but there is a javascript file is not displayed after loading content. This is my code:

**index.html.twig**
.

This is the function in **ajax_backend.js** to load content:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', "#myModal", function (e) {
    // load content inside modal from the link
    var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
    showLoadingDiv();

    $(this).load(link.attr("href"), function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
        if (statusTxt == "success") {
            collectionInsideModal();
            hideLoadingDiv();
        }
        if (statusTxt == "error")
            alert("Erreur: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        hideLoadingDiv();
    });

    $(this).on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        $(this).html('');
    });
});
```

after loading the content , the file **nifty.min.js** is not displayed so I must reload this file with the content like this :

```
 <div>
 // content that will be loaded
 </div>
 <script src="{{ asset('backend/js/nifty.min.js') }}"></script>
```

how to fix it to avoid reloading the JS file with content each time ?

**This is the the file [nifty.min.js](https://gist.github.com/houssem04/2973d77b1be2436d6bf4bff916010626) not minified**

Comment: Simplest solution would be to put the actual script inside the tag - jquery will evaluate an inline script.  A more elegant solution would be to call the parts of that script that you need again after the new content has been inserted.

Comment: Is the code in nifty.min.js executed? Just because the HTML script tag does not show up in the DOM, doesn't mean the code isn't executed.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: nifty.min.js gives some css to form and it's not executed when loading content, but if I reload it with the content it is executed

Comment: @Dave: hello, what do you mean by "put the actual script inside the tag" ?

Comment: this is the nifty.min.js  https://gist.github.com/houssem04/2973d77b1be2436d6bf4bff916010626

Comment: Add $(document).ready(function() {  at the top inside you're js file so it loads after the div is made?!